# Displaying folder contents in HTML with fs and an http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I've written a function that returns the files of a folder.

```
function getAttachments() {
    fs.readdir('dir/to/scan/', function(err, files) {
        var returnStr = '';
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        }

        files.forEach(function(file) {
            returnStr += '<li>' + file + '</li>';
        })
        console.log(typeof returnStr);
        console.log(returnStr);
        return(returnStr);
    })
}
```

Then i've got my html template where I call the function

```
var template = `
<ul>` 
+ getAttachments() + `
</ul>
`;
```

I use `res.write(template)` 
The console log returns

```
<li>file1.txt</li>
<li>file2.txt</li>
```

But the HTML that is rendered
on the browser as

```
<ul>
undefined
</ul>
```

I'm not sure why I'm logging the string successfully, but I can't return it successfully.

Comment: Your method "getAttachments" returns nothing. The returned statement is nested in the `readdir` callback, not in the function's first level scope. What you can do, though I don't recommand it, is using `fs.readdirSync`, which is synchronous, and returns the value instead of using a callback.

Comment: I had tried moving the the return variable into the first level scope, but neither the logs or the return values worked for me anymore.  I've gotten it to work very easily with the synchronous version.  Given the simplicity of my problem it seems like a good solution.  Is there any reason you wouldn't recommend readdirSync other than speed (and learning async programming as a benefit in the long run)?

Comment: This eslint rule should answer your question : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sync. The sync methods are easy to use, but are more of a "quick & dirty" solution. Sure, I still use them from time to time when I write a throwaway script, but it should not appear in a real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAttachments` doesn't return anything in the snippet you've posted above. The real issue is that you have nothing of value to return at that point since `readdir` is asynchronous. In order to make this work you'll need to make the template asynchronously as well, and pass in a callback to `getAttachments`

Here is `getAttachments` when it consumes a callback:

```
function getAttachments(cb) {
    fs.readdir('dir/to/scan/', function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            cb(err);
        } else {
            var returnStr = '';
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                returnStr += '<li>' + file + '</li>';
            })
            console.log(typeof returnStr);
            console.log(returnStr);
            cb(null, returnStr);
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can get the attachments and construct a template string like this:

```
getAttachments(function(err, listEntries) {
    var template = `<ul>${listEnties}<ul>`;
    // ... use template here. 
});
```

There is an obvious downside here in that now you can only construct the template asynchronously, but that is just part of using node.js.

You can look at using `fs.readdirSync` if you *really* need it to be synchronous, but this goes against the grain in the language since you are making a blocking call.